# Jitsi android SDK skip join meeting page and join room automatically?

Tags: android, jitsi-meet, videocall

I’m building an android chat application and use Jitsi SDK for video call ,
Users see a join meeting before joining the room.

[image]

How can I disable this step and join room automaticaly.
I try to set some server configs in /etc/jitsi/meet/…-config.js

```
 prejoinPageEnabled: false,
 prejoinConfig: {
        // When 'true', it shows an intermediate page before joining, where the user can configure their devices.
    //     // This replaces `prejoinPageEnabled`.
        enabled: false,
    //     // Hides the participant name editing field in the prejoin screen.
    //     // If requireDisplayName is also set as true, a name should still be provided through
    //     // either the jwt or the userInfo from the iframe api init object in order for this to have an effect.
    //     hideDisplayName: true,
    //     // List of buttons to hide from the extra join options dropdown.
    //     hideExtraJoinButtons: ['no-audio', 'by-phone'],
     },
```

and set prejoinConfig config in differents way in android client

```
.setConfigOverride("prejoinPageEnabled", false)
.setConfigOverride("prejoinConfig.enabled", false)
.setConfigOverride("prejoinconfig.enabled", false)
.setConfigOverride("prejoinPageEnabled", false)
.setConfigOverride("prejoinConfig.enabled", false)
```

But none of the methods worked and users see meeting room page and should press join meeting button to join the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.setFeatureFlag("prejoinpage.enabled", false)
```